# Is there any way to find out on which table am I when I am scrolling on a specific table?

Tags: html, reactjs, html-table

I have built a react website where i have put 7 tables each one with a scroll-bar. What I am trying to do is to turn the day from the image below on another color when I am scrolling on the table-scroll-bar beneath it. Here is an image of my website with the tables:

[image]

And my code:

```
private imageShow(movieList:MovieData[])
    {
    return <div id="table-scroll">
    <table > 
        <tbody>
          <tr> <td>   
          {movieList.map(movie =>
          <div>
          <button className ='search-button'> {movie.name} </button>
          <button className ='image-padding'> <img src={"data:image/jpeg;base64," + movie.image} /> </button>
          </div>
          )}
          </td> </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

}

private scrollBar(movieList: MovieData[])
{

    let imageShow = this.imageShow(movieList);
    return <div>
    <div id="table-wrapper">
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    {imageShow}
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: `What I am trying to do is to turn the day from the image below on another color when I am scrolling on the table-scroll-bar beneath it`.  Could you please clarify that?  I'm not sure what you're after.

Comment: Well, for example if I'm scrolling the first table, the one underneath 'Monday', I want to turn 'Monday' text from color white to color blue for example. So for that, I need to know on which table I'm scrolling at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a listener for the [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) for each table/heading pair.

In your event handler, you would style the heading based on the value of `table.scrollY`, where `table` is one of your `table-scroll` elements.